# Jquery validation form with TinyMCE field who gives no error by empty value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tinymce

I have the following jQuery Validation script with the TinyMCE editor: http://www.zinomen.com/test/validate.html

By the firstname and lastname you get an error when the fields are empty, but at the message field you get no error.

I use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert('submitted, value of message = '+ tinyMCE.get('message').getContent()); }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 15
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Please fill in your firstname",
                minlength: "Your firstname must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            lastname: {
                required: "Please fill in your lastname",
                minlength: "Your lastname must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please fill in your message",
                minlength: "Your message must consist of at least 15 characters"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The value of the tinyMCE field you get with: `tinyMCE.get('message').getContent();` and in the form you have `<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>`

Can anybody help me, to get by a empty message field also an error with jquery validate?

Comment: you need to keep in mind that tinymce is a realtime editor and validate will count the characters of the html tags too. 15 characters are reached fast cause "<p>123456789</p>" are already 15 or 16 characters.

Answer (score 1):

working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jNJ2G/1/

I used the [TinyMCE jQuery plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js) and created a custom rule for jquery validation

```
$('#message').tinymce({
                    // Location of TinyMCE script
                    script_url : 'http://www.zinomen.com/test/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                    // General options
                    theme : "advanced",
                    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

                    // Theme options
                    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

                    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                    content_css : "css/content.css",

                    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",
            });

$.validator.addMethod("textInMce", function textInMce(value, element){
    return $('#message').html().length > 15;
}, "Please over 15 chars.");
$.validator.classRuleSettings.textInMce= { textInMce: true };

$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "Please fill in your firstname",
            minlength: "Your firstname must consist of at least 2 characters"
        },
        lastname: {
            required: "Please fill in your lastname",
            minlength: "Your lastname must consist of at least 2 characters"
        }
    }
});
if ($("#signupForm").valid())
    alert('succes');
```

**Edit** now this pastebin sample that does work :)
http://pastebin.com/cDJ9033C

Comment: at least a partial solution. After hitting submit with a filled editor and then removal of the editor content + submit will yield no error. Additionally jQuery validate won't work onKeyUp!

Comment: line 42 of the pastebin should be: `return $('#message').text().length > 15;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because of the fact that `$("#signupForm")` refers to a form that does not "contain" the editor but the editor source html lement - your textarea. Tinymce uses a html element like a textarea to get and write the editor contents to, but tinymce like most rte editors creates a contenteditable iframe to edit content.

Validation does not work cause there will be no keyup events on your textarea - those events get fired in the editor iframe (i guess validation will work if you hit the submit button (?) ).

In order to make your code work you will have to write the editorcontents back on keyup and fire/trigger a keyup event on form element (this might not work using some IE browsers).

You may do this using the [tinymce setup configuration paramter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup). Here is an example of what to write in your tinymce init function (configuration):

```
theme : "advanced",
plugins: "style, paste, wordcount",
...
setup : function(ed){

    ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, event) {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
            $("#signupForm#message").trigger({type: 'keyup', ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey, altKey: event.altKey, which: event.keyCode, event:eventObject });
    });
},
...
```