# jquery inline form validation with tinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce, validation

I protect my form using [jquery inline validation](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/). in textarea i have tinyMCE editor. now i need to check my form validation empty textarea . any way to work this ?

tinyMCE :

```
tinyMCE.init({ mode : "textareas", theme : "advanced",directionality : "rtl",theme_advanced_buttons3 : "", theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",height:'100%',theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",});
```

HTML and validation : `( set class="validate[required]" and id="description")`

```
<textarea id="description" class="validate[required]"  name="description" style="width:100%" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you running into a specific error or problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this to SO-Questions. I guess this is what you are looking for:

- [Jquery validation form with TinyMCE field who gives no error by empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131526/jquery-validation-form-with-tinymce-field-who-gives-no-error-by-empty-value/10137313#10137313)
- [validating multiple TinyMCE Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309732/validating-multiple-tinymce-editor/10313069#10313069)