# tinyMCE jQuery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to use tinymce's `getContent()` to make a custom validation rule,  how can I do this with jquery validation? I need to apply the rule to a textarea formatted with tinymce.

Validation: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

```
$("#element").click( function(e) {

    console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

    $("#someForm").validate({
        rules: {        
            title: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I'm thinking of just using a little bit of javascript with getContent() because it looks like there's just as much effort creating a workaround to get jquery validation working with tinymce. Thoughts on possible solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following stackoverflow questions should help you on that issue:

- [validating multiple TinyMCE Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309732/validating-multiple-tinymce-editor)
- [Jquery validation form with TinyMCE field who gives no error by empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131526/jquery-validation-form-with-tinymce-field-who-gives-no-error-by-empty-value)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your are not getting client side validation on form submit time when you are with tinymce try this code 
suppose your have two html editor 1 is txtAboutCompanyand 2 is txtProductinfo

**this is client side code**

```
<div class="divclass">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
  <span class="field-validation-error" id="AC" style="margin:9px 0 0 157px;"></span>
</div>
```

**this is jquery**

```
$("#BusinessProfile").click(function () {
        var aboutC = $("#txtAboutCompany").val()
        var pinfo = $("#txtProductinfo").val();
        if (aboutC == "" && pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#bpform").valid();

            return false;
        } else if (aboutC == "") {
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
            $("#txtAboutCompany").focus();

            $("#bpform").valid();
            return false;
        } else if (pinfo == "") {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("")
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
            $("#txtProductinfo").focus();
            $("#bpform").valid();

            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#AC").append("").val("").html("");
            $("#PI").append("").val("").html("");
            //return true;
            $("#bpform").validate();
        }
    });
```

you can get your all required validation on form submit time

I know this is not proper way but you can do it .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371966/tinymce-jquery-form-validation/22170043#22170043

Answer (score 0):

```
function tinymceValidation() {
    var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    if (content === "" || content === null) {
        $("#questionValid").html("<span>Please enter question statement</span>");
    } else {
        $("#questionValid").html("");
    }
}

tinymce.activeEditor.on('keyup', function (e) {
    debugger;
    tinymceValidation();
});

$(form).submit(function (e) {
    tinymceValidation();
});
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303605/4284627) about code-only answers and edit your answer to add explanations.