# Validate TINYMCE before form submission?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using js.validate plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Im also using TINYMCE.

Upon form submission I save the content of TINYMCE to it's text area:

```
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
$('#article').val(content);
```

My question is, how can I validate this using js validate?

I've tried:

```
rules: {

    article: 'required'

},
```

Article is the name of the text area. This does not work, I get no error coming up.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371966/tinymce-jquery-form-validation

Comment: Not a duplicate. The links in the answer do not tackle my question, they only show how to get the contents of tinymce