# Can't validate TinyMCE in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, tinymce

I have a form that use unobtrusive validation. Recently I have changed text area to use tiny mce and now validation doesn't work.
I have tried to use solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858591/unable-to-get-tinymce-working-with-jquery-unobtrusive-validation) but nothing happens.

```
$('#form input[type=submit]').click(function () {
```

Never executes.
 Here what I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UserAd", FormMethod.Post))
{
...
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { id = "description" })        
...
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
...
```

This is JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            skin: "o2k7",
            height: "250",
            plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",


            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_resizing: false
        });

        function toggleEditor(id) {
            if (!tinyMCE.get(id)) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
            }
            else {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
            }
        }


        // new
        $(function () {
            var tinymce = $('#Description');

            tinymce.tinymce({
                setup: function (e) {
                    e.onInit.add(function () {
                        tinymce.css({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            height: 0,
                            width: 0,
                            top: -100
                        }).show();
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#form input[type=submit]').click(function () {
                alert('ss');
                tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            });
        });
        // makes form field highlighting work with bootstrap's css
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            }

        });
        $(function () {
            // makes form field highlighting work with bootstrap's css on post backs
            $('.input-validation-error').each(function (i, element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').not('.error').addClass('error');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying an ID of "#form" in your selector. Try removing the # from your selector.

E.G,

```
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function () {
      alert('ss');
      tinyMCE.triggerSave();
});
```

Additionally, if I am reading the code right, the tinyMCE is a dynamic element. You may want to bind the click event with the on function.

E.G,

```
$("body").on("click","#yourFormID", function(e){
    your click stuff here
}
```

Comment: What's the ID of your form? See my updated answer. It may be because your element is dynamic, try using the on() function for your click handler per my example.

Comment: I added the id to a form and this function but no luck again :(

Comment: Any error in firebug? Can you verify the ID is on the form within the DOM?

Comment: When I run application on the page with this form in console I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinymce' In the code it's just bellow '//new'

Comment: Ah, looks like your casing is off. Try this.

tinyMCE.tinymce instead of the tinymce.tinymce you have there.

Comment: Now I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tinymce'" It seams that it is casting in question.

Comment: Can you not just do $('#Description').tinyMCE({ stuff here })

Comment: Just something else I noticed, it looks like you are specifying the ID of the textarea in all lower case. @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { id = "description" }). But in your javascript, you are specifying the first letter being capitalized.  var tinymce = $('#Description'); These should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is exactly what it says. You need to load Tiny MCE (not the plugin, the real deal) before jQuery. That may be the problem.

Can you check whether tiny_mce.js is actually downloaded? You might also want to check [this blog](http://brian.pontarelli.com/2007/09/12/how-to-get-jquery-and-tinymce-to-work/). It is from someone who also had problems with Tiny MCE.

Answer (score 0):

Since the TextArea is made hidden after you apply the tinyMce plugin, and since as default hidden fileds are not validated, you need to change this default. Have you already tried to add:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
ignore: ''
```

});

Comment: I tried and that and nothing, what ever I do tiny mce text area is not validated

Answer (score 0):

There are several stackoverflow questions for this issue already that will solve this.
Have a look here

- [Jquery validation form with TinyMCE field who gives no error by empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131526/jquery-validation-form-with-tinymce-field-who-gives-no-error-by-empty-value)
- [validating multiple TinyMCE Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309732/validating-multiple-tinymce-editor)